# Two applications in solution: Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'App.xbf'

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

There is MainApplication + BackgroundAudioTask. Then I was create another Windows Phone 8.1 blank app in the same solution for unit testing purpose, naming it UnitTestApp.

UnitTestApp resefrs to the MainApplication (as well to BackgroundAudioTask and some needed libs)

In VS 2013 Update 4 this solution do not compile. Error:

```
Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'App.xbf'. Source files: 
C:\Projects\Solution\UnitTestApp\bin\Debug\App.xbf
C:\Projects\Solution\MainApplication\bin\Debug\App.xbf
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Do you solve this issue? I have received it too.

Comment: Hi, @ViacheslavSmityukh! No, but I use a workaround. I was include unit tests in the main project. After I was add Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'" in .csproj file for them.  It nice work for me and unit tests will not added to production release code.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same error, but the files with same name were "Assets/ApplicationIcon.png".
i fixed it with excluding the Assets-folder from the unittest-project.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, either. It results in an unhandled exception once I try to run the unit tests.

Comment: In the settings for the unit test project I set the assets to "None" and deleted the Assets folder from the solution entirely and that did the trick for me.